# How to list all variables names and their current values?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

How to list all variables names and their current values?

Including not only `$HOME`, `$PWD` etc but any other you have defined.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/420295/how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-currently-defined-environment-variables-in-a-linux-ba

Comment: You've accepted an incorrect answer. "printenv" only gives you the environment variables. If you truly want all variables currently declared in your shell, use "declare -p" or "typeset -p".

Answer (score 712, accepted):

**For bash:** (the standard shell in Ubuntu)

Enter the following command in a terminal to print all the environment variables:

```
printenv
```

For further information about this command, read the [`printenv` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/printenv.1.html).

---

To show a list including the "shell variables" you can enter the next command:

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | less
```

This will show you *not only* the shell variables, but the environment variables too.

For more information related with this topic read:

- [How to list variables declared in script in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1305237/1505348) from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) and
- [How to print all environment variables defined (but not necessarily
  exported) in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3510/53809) from
  [UnixSE](http://unix.stackexchange.com)
- [Environment variable vs Shell variable, what's the difference?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference)

---

**For zsh:** (an advanced shell)

Use the following command:

```
( setopt posixbuiltin; set; ) | less
```

For more information about ZSH options, see [`zshoptions` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/zshoptions.1.html).

Comment: If I go to the terminal and write `MYNEWVARIABLE=Ubuntu` and execute `printenv` it doesn't show there. Why is that, and how do those others show up?

Comment: Probably you are seeing the difference between a shell variable and an environment variable. Try `export MYNEWVARIABLE=Ubuntu` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: if you simply execute `set`, it lists the variable created by you as well. Or do `set | grep myvar`

Comment: `printenv` is an external command, so it only knows about (and prints) exported environment variables.  `set` is an internal bash command, so it shows all the "shell variables" (unexported environment variables) as well as the exported environment variables.

Comment: Works on OSX too

Comment: To expand on @Rmano's reply to @Strapakowsky... This will not work
`unset MYNEWVARIABLE; MYNEWVARIABLE=Ubuntu; printenv | grep MYNEW`, but this will
`unset MYNEWVARIABLE; export MYNEWVARIABLE=Ubuntu; printenv | grep MYNEW`, and this will
`unset MYNEWVARIABLE; MYNEWVARIABLE=Ubuntu printenv | grep MYNEW`. Using export says "the variable I'm setting should be part of the environment that gets passed to processes, not just a variable in this shell." My third example says "the variable should be part of the environment that gets passed to THIS process, but not stick around afterward."

Comment: ` -o posix` is bash only, not for `sh`

Comment: This is incorrect. env or printenv only print environment variables. To get ALL VARIABLES declared in your current shell, use "declare -p" or "typeset -p". See another answer on this page.

Comment: I like this answer for Bash, but the POSIX `set` omits some shell variables. You can get them all with `declare -p | while read -r _ flags line; do printf "%s\n" "$line"; done`.

Comment: FWIW, I discovered this using: `diff <( set -o posix; set | while read -r line; do printf "%s\n" "${line%%=*}"; done | sort) <(declare -p | while read -r _ flags line; do printf "%s\n" "${line%%=*}"; done | sort)` to compare the outputs of each. Omitted variables were: `BASHPID`, `BASH_ARGV0`, `EPOCH{REALTIME,SECONDS}`, `FUNCNAME`, `HISTCMD`, `LINENO`, `OLDPWD`, `RANDOM`, and `SECONDS`.

Answer (score 110):

You can see all variables with the `declare` builtin.

```
declare -p
```

If you're only interested in environment variables, use

```
declare -xp
```

Run `help declare` to see what the other options are.

Comment: this is far neat-er solution than `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 set` and it is also worthy of mention that `declare` is `alias` (in that context) for `typeset`, another bash builtin.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: I think this is what most people are looking for.

Comment: for the sake of convenience the following bash oneliner prints names of all environment variables: `declare -xp | grep --perl-regexp --only-match '(?<=^declare -x )[^=]+'`

Comment: @maoizm If you want only the variable names and nothing else, it's easier to use compgen for that. `compgen -e`.

Comment: Works in ZSH too, thank you!

Comment: A useful addition, if you just want just the names and not the values: `declare -p | while read -r _ flags line; do printf "%s\n" "${line%%=*}"; done`. (Variables with values that contain embedded newlines, e.g. `IFS`, will add a blank line.)

Comment: @ColinFraizer try `compgen -v` instead

Comment: That is nice. Thanks! (Oddity: when called from top level—not within a function—`declare -p` includes `FUNCNAME`, but `compgen -v` does not. When called within a function, the output is identical.)

Comment: In zsh, use `declare -p1` to prettify the printed variables for readability

Comment: What if I want all variables except the environment?

Comment: @Velkan that's a bit harder as there's no option with either declare or compgen that lists all but env vars, but you can get that list of variable names by grabbing all variable names (compgen -v) and removing the environment variables (compgen -e) from that. E.g. with `comm -23 <(compgen -v) <(compgen -e)`

Comment: `declare -f` prints all functions. `declare -F` prints all function names and their export status. `declare -f someFunction` prints some function

Answer (score 66):

I know that this question is quite old and  answered, but I think I can add a bit of useful information.

In all the methods described above, the procedure that is suggested is:

- launch a terminal
- show the environment variables using `env`, or
  `printenv` or whatever

The problem of these solutions are that you are seeing the environment variables *of the shell that is running into the terminal*. You are not seeing the environment variables available to an application run, for example, directly by the graphic interface.

This is noticeable if, for example, you use your `~/.profile`, or `.bashrc`, or `.zshenv` (depending on your shell) to modify the environment variables --- like the classic addition of directories to the path.

To see the environment variables available to the application started directly in the graphic environment, you can do the following (in Gnome Shell, I am sure there is an equivalent method in all the other DE):

- press Alt-F2
- run the command `xterm -e bash --noprofile --norc`

(Or, if you do not have `xterm`, `gnome-terminal -- bash --noprofile --norc` --- thanks to @Mike Nakis for the comment).

You now have a terminal with a shell that did not add any environment variables. You can use `env` here to list all your environment variables:

[image: Example of the bare shell]

Obviously the new shell  will have the environment variables added by the system files, but that variables should be available (by inheritance) to all programs in the system anyway.

I am posting this because it's the fourth time I have to search this trick again, checking my `.pam_environment` file. So now I will find it faster (and in the process, I hope helping someone else...)

Comment: Requires you have a desktop environment, not useful for server CLI-only folk.

Comment: Yes --- but then for CLI only the previous answer is ok. I was just pointing out that sometime you need to check environment variables available to application started by the graphical environment, which is not the same set you see when you start a terminal in it. For example, if you are trying to understand why your Kile app can't compile a LaTeX file, while in a terminal you can, the trick I posted here will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for a very useful answer! I just linked to it from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Desktop_environment_specifics

Comment: Thanks. Did you recommend `xterm -e bash --noprofile --norc` because the startup files are not read and executed when Ubuntu is started with graphical interface ? See https://askubuntu.com/q/1025845/1471

Comment: @Tim basically it's just a way to have a shell without anything more than the environment variables available to the graphic environment. A standard terminal will read (or re-read) `.bashrc` for example...

Comment: the right command to execute nowadays (Ubuntu 18.04) is `gnome-terminal -- bash --noprofile --norc`

Comment: But what if the graphic application changed it‘s environment variables (e.g. due some settings)? Isn‘t there a way to check out the actual environment variables of any process by it‘s PID?

Comment: @Arber I think that's worth a new question....

Answer (score 17):

In bash using compgen:

```
compgen -v | while read line; do echo $line=${!line};done
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as all others list more than just the name itself. In my case some variables contain multiline values which makes the other solutions not feasable.

Comment: A variant: `compgen -v | while read line; do declare -p $line; done`

Comment: @Eljay what is the difference to just `declare -p`?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy • `declare -p` won't include things like `BASH_COMMAND`, `BASH_SUBSHELL`, `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, `HISTCMD`, `LINENO`, `RANDOM`, `SECONDS`.

Comment: @Eljay well... at least for me `declare -p` "includes" resp. lists them all (and `FUNCNAME` additionally), but you are kind of right: the **values are not shown** and also **values of arrays are not shown**. do you know why this is? **--** so IMHO your line is the most comprehensive way to do this, even with all values of arrays including indexes!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy • I don't know why that is.  My guess is the programmer for those things did not think it was useful, and hence the various strategies (or workarounds) to get that information.

Answer (score 16):

To list the environment variables in terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> you can use `env` command.

for example :

```
[raja@localhost ~]$ env
XDG_VTNR=1
SSH_AGENT_PID=3671
XDG_SESSION_ID=3
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP=yes
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/raja/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:3691:1
GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH=:
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=
HISTSIZE=1000
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=0250277dd805498381e96c05d88068b0-1364679772.845276-1676152201
WINDOWID=65011716
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/raja/.cache/keyring-N3QoQ2
IMSETTINGS_MODULE=none
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1
USER=raja
```

etc.

hope that helps.

Comment: I've noticed that env misses some variables o_O. specifically after sourcing a VAR=VAL file.

Comment: @ThorSummoner The answer here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474650/unix-what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-export

Answer (score 9):

Most solutions here either print only environment variables, or have the drawback that env or (set -o posix; set) do not print values in easily parseable form (try to print variable A=$'a\r\nb', it has multiple lines...).

Here is a function that will print all variables, one variable per line, in the POSIX escaped form (works properly for simple text variables, does not work for arrays):

```
function dump_vars {
    local VARNAME
    compgen -v | while read -r VARNAME; do
        printf "$VARNAME=%q\n" "${!VARNAME}"
    done
}
```

Thanks to @tmgoblin for pointing out the use of compgen -v.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a specific environment variable, rather than printing them all with `printenv`, you can for example print it by doing `echo "$PWD"`

Comment: The quotes are unnecessary; i.e.: `echo $PATH` or `echo $USER`. This will print the environment variable's value. The dollar sign operator is the only thing needed to access the value of a variable or command.

Answer (score 4):

**env** is a [POSIX 7 way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html):

```
export asdf=qwer
env | grep asdf
```

Sample output:

```
asdf=qwer
```

It only shows exported variables: non-exported variables are not usually considered "environment variables".

Prefer that over `printenv`, which is not POSIX. Both seem to do the same thing without arguments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123473/what-is-the-difference-between-env-and-printenv

Comment: Already mentioned two years ago: http://askubuntu.com/a/276162/158442

Comment: @muru fair enough. Wish it had made `env` more visible with better formatting,  and I've added more info.

Comment: That's what [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/276162/edit) is for.

Answer (score 4):

- `printenv` will show all the global environoment variables
- env, global environment variable after login modification
- set, will display all local environment variable, relative to the session (usually the local var is the global + the particular of the session)

Answer (score 1):

printenv only lists exported variables,
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>
( "\e$": complete-variable )
will list all variables.

Answer (score 1):

Script to dump everything, sort, and highlight all $ENVS and $variables declared in the session.

```
#!/bin/bash
temp="$(mktemp)"
declare > $temp
printenv >> $temp;
sort -u $temp -o $temp;
grep --color=auto -E '^[A-Za-z_]+[^=]+' $temp 
rm -i $temp
```