# What are the standard Environment variables ($) in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I know some useful environment-variables like `$HOME`, `$UID`, `$BASH`, `$LOGNAME` etc. which is useful to get information in terminal/command-line with using `echo`(ex: `echo $LOGNAME`)

I want to know what are the useful Environment variables available in Ubuntu? In other words **Where I can find a list of useful standard bash environment-variables for Ubuntu with their uses**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `env` command on your terminal. It will list all the available environment variables.

See also the [Ubuntu wiki on Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Also refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values) question to know more about environment variables.

Comment: I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values link on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables but not in related Question when asking. Then What is about my question (Is it can be different? or Duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

Execute `set` command in terminal to get all environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of all standard variables in `bash` - even the ones that are not useful - until one day when you need them:

Search for `Shell Variables` in `man bash` in the section [PARAMETERS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13):

```
LESS="+/The following variables are set by the shell" man bash
```