# What is the difference between env, declare and compgen -v?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I see that `printenv` and `env` are giving the same output. When digging further for getting the complete list of environment variables, I found     `declare -xp` and the command from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values):

```
compgen -v | while read line; do echo $line=${!line};done
```

What are the differences between these commands in terms of environment variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `env` command can run other commands with modified environments. If no command is given, `env` prints environment variables (i.e., **exported** variables). `printenv` can only print environment variables (it cannot run commands). See [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123473/70524) for more differences between the two.

[`compgen -v`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) outputs only **names** of all shell variables, exported or not. That's why you have to use variable indirection (`${!line}`) to get the value of the variable. `compgen -v` is typically used for tab completion.

`declare -p` prints details of the shell variables in a re-usable manner, typically in the form of more `declare` commands. The `-x` option restricts the output to exported variables. The output of `declare` can be `eval`'d later, to get back a given state of variables.

`set` can be used to set various shell options, or the positional parameters. If no arguments or options are given, then it prints **all shell variables and functions**.

`export` can be used to export variables or functions. With the `-p` option, it prints exported variables and functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW can you please mention something about 'set' command also?