# Why aren't variables like $PS1 in printenv?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, ps1

From what I can tell `printenv` displays environment variables, but why don't I see other variables like `PS1` for customizing the shell prompt?

What exactly is `printenv` outputting and why doesn't it pick up `PS1`? Is there a more comprehensive output command that does more than `printenv`?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Examining_values_of_environment_variables

Comment: Thanks for the link but that isn't the question

Comment: It shows a method to list all variables, including shell variables which are not exported. But you also got a more complete answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson As far as I could tell it doesn't show that method on that page, just a link to an answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values/356973#356973 that doesn't work in my terminal

Comment: You should see them all if you run `set` with no arguments

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [How to print apparently hidden environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68232/how-to-print-apparently-hidden-environment-variables)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `PS1` is not normally exported.

Environment variables are used to set the execution environment of child processes; since `PS1` only really has significance within an interactive shell, there's not normally any point exporting it - it is just a plain *shell variable*.

If you start an interactive child *shell*, then it will read and set its `PS1` from the shell's resource file such as `~/.bashrc`

If you `export PS1` then you will see it in the `printenv` output. Alternatively you can see plain shell variables using the bash builtin `set` as described here [How to list all variables names and their current values?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all the terminology used in this answer. What does it mean for an environmental variable to be "exported"? Normally when I see tutorials about saving e.g. shell formatting, you "export PS1=" in the `.bash_profile` file for example. Does exporting just mean "saved / persisted across terminal sessions"?

Comment: @ArukaJ a shell variable is just a shell variable until it is exported - only then does it become an environment variable. Exporting simply makes it available to child processes of the current shell (i.e. becomes part of their *environment*) - nothing to do with persistence across different terminal sessions.

Comment: So is it accurate to say that PS1 is not actually an environmental variable but rather a shell variable, at least until I decide to export it in my bash profile?

Comment: Also what exactly is meant by "child process of the current shell"

Comment: How would I "start an interactive child shell"?

Comment: @WEFX type `bash` at an existing shell prompt

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a more comprehensive output command that does more than `printenv`?

`printenv` prints only [*environment variables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), which may be considered an advantage. But if you want to print shell variables as well, use `echo "$x"` (or `printf '%s\n' "$x"`, which [is more robust](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)) instead of `printenv x`.

[**steeldriver's explanation**](https://askubuntu.com/a/960555/22949) of these issues is useful and correct, but I'm presenting the topic in another way here.

[`printenv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/printenv.1.html) is an external command--not [built into](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) your shell, but a separate program from your shell. It shows *its own* environment variables, which are those it inherits from the shell you use to run it. However, **shells don't pass all their variables into their [subprocesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process)' environments**. Instead they maintain a distinction between which variables are *environment variables* and which are not. (Those that are not are often call *shell variables*.)

---

### Shell Variables

To see how this works, try these commands, which are enclosed in `(` `)` so they act independently<sup>**1**</sup> of one another. Individually, each of these commands works the same when you run it *without* the `(` `)`, but variables you create in earlier commands would still exist in later commands. Running the commands in subshells prevents this.

Creating a new variable, then running an external command, does not pass the variable into the command's environment. Except in the unusual case that you already have an environment variable `x`, this command produces no output:

```bash
(x=foo; printenv x)
```

The variable *is* assigned in the shell, though. This command outputs `foo`:

```bash
(x=foo; echo "$x")
```

The shell supports syntax to pass a variable into a command's environment *without* affecting the current shell's environment. This outputs `foo`:

```bash
x=foo printenv x
```

(That works in a subshell, too, of course--`(x=foo printenv x)`--but I've shown it without the `(` `)` because when you use that syntax, nothing is set for your current shell, so using a subshell is unnecessary to prevent subsequent commands from being affected.)

This prints `foo`, then prints `bar`:

```bash
(x=bar; x=foo printenv x; echo "$x")
```

### Exporting

**When you export a variable, it is automatically passed into the environments of all subsequent external commands run from the same shell.** The `export` command does this. You can use it before you define the variable, after you define it, or you can even define the variable *in* the `export` command itself. All these print `foo`:

```bash
(x=foo; export x; printenv x)
```

```bash
(export x; x=foo; printenv x)
```

```bash
(export x=foo; printenv x)
```

There is no `unexport` command. Even though you can export a variable before setting it, unsetting a variable also unexports it, which is to say that this prints nothing, rather than printing `bar`:

```bash
(x=foo; export x; unset x; x=bar; printenv x)
```

But *changing* the value of a variable after exporting it *does* affect the exported value. This prints `foo`,  then `bar`:

```bash
(export x=foo; printenv x; x=bar; printenv x)
```

Like other processes, your shell itself inherits environment variables from its parent process. Such variables are present initially in your shell's environment and they are automatically exported--or *remain* exported, if you choose to think of it that way. This prints `foo` (remember, `VAR=val cmd` runs `cmd` with `VAR` set to `val` in its environment):

```bash
x=foo bash -c 'printenv x'
```

Variables set in child processes do not affect the parent process, even if they are exported. This prints `foo` (not `bar`):

```bash
(x=foo; bash -c 'export x=bar'; echo "$x")
```

### Subshells

A subshell is also a child process<sup>**2**</sup>; this also prints `foo`:

```bash
(x=foo; (export x=bar); echo "$x")
```

That should make clearer why I've enclosed most of these commands in `(` `)` to run them in subshells.

Subshells are special, though. Unlike other subprocesses, such as those created when you run an external command like `printenv` or `bash`, [a subshell inherits most of its parent shell's state](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell). In particular, **subshells inherit even variables that aren't exported**. Just as `(x=foo; echo "$x")` prints `foo`, so does `(x=foo; (echo "$x"))`.

The unexported variable is still not exported in the subshell--unless you export it--so, just as `(x=foo; printenv x)` prints nothing, so does `(x=foo; (printenv x))`.

A subshell is a special kind of subprocess that is a shell. *Not all subprocesses that are shells are subshells.* The shell created by running `bash` is [not a subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261661/11938) and it does not inherit unexported variables. So this command prints a blank line (because `echo` prints a newline even when called with an empty argument):

```bash
(x=foo; bash -c 'echo "$x"')
```

### Why `PS1` isn't an environment variable (and usually shouldn't be one)

Finally, as for why prompt variables like `PS1` are shell variables but not environment variables, the reasons are:

1. They're only needed in the shell, not other programs.
2. They are set for each interactive shell, and noninterative shells don't need them at all. That is, they don't need to be inherited.
3. Attempting to pass `PS1` to a new shell would typically fail, because **the shell usually resets `PS1`.**

Point #3 deserves a bit more explanation, though if you never attempt to make `PS1` an environment variable, then you probably don't really *need* to know the details.

#### When Bash starts noninteractively, it unsets `PS1`.

When a noninteractive Bash shell starts up, it always<sup>**3**</sup> *unsets* `PS1`. This prints a blank line (not `foo`):

```bash
PS1=foo bash -c 'echo "$PS1"'
```

To verify that it is actually unset, and not just set but empty, you can run this, which prints `unset`:

```bash
PS1=foo bash -c 'if [[ -v PS1 ]]; then echo set; else echo unset; fi'
```

To verify that this is independent of other startup behavior, you could try passing any combination of `--login`, `--norc`, or `--posix` before `-c`, or setting `BASH_ENV` to the path of some script (e.g., `BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc PS1=foo bash ...`), or `ENV` if you passed `--posix`. In no case does a noninteractive Bash shell fail to unset `PS1`.

What this means is that if you export `PS1` and run a non-interactive shell which *itself* runs an interactive shell, it won't set have the `PS1` value you originally set. For this reason--and also because other shells besides Bash (like Ksh) don't all behave the same way, and the way you write `PS1` for Bash does not always work for those shells--I recommend against attempting to make `PS1` an environment variable. Just edit `~/.bashrc` to set whatever prompt you want.

#### When Bash starts interactively, it *often* sets or resets `PS1`.

Conversely, if you *unset* `PS1` and run an interactive Bash shell, even if you prevent it from running commands from startup scripts by passing `--norc`, it will still automatically *set* `PS1` to a default value. Running `env -u PS1 bash --norc` gives you an interactive Bash shell with `PS1` set to `\s-\v\$` . Since Bash expands `\s` to the name of the shell and `\v` to the version number, this shows `bash-4.3$`  as the prompt on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Note that setting `PS1`'s value as the *empty* string is not the same as unsetting it. As explained below, running `PS1= bash` gives you an interactive shell with strange startup behavior. You should avoid exporting `PS1` when it is set to the empty string, in practical use, unless you understand and want that behavior.

However, if you set `PS1` and run an interactive Bash shell--and it doesn't get unset by an intermediary noninteractive shell--it will keep that value... until a startup script like the global `/etc/profile` (for login shells) or `/etc/bash.bashrc`, or your per-user `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.bash_profile` (all for login shells) or `~/.bashrc` resets it.

Even if you edit those files to prevent them from setting `PS1`--which, in the case of `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`, I recommend against doing anyway, since they affect all users--you can't really rely on this. As mentioned above, interactive shells started from noninteractive shells won't have `PS1`, unless you were to reset and reexport it in the noninteractive shell. Furthermore, you should think twice before doing that, because it is common for shell code (including shell functions you may have defined) to check `PS1` to determine whether the shell it's running in is interactive or noninteractive.

#### Checking `PS1` is a common way to determine if the current shell is interactive.

This is why it is so important for noninteractive Bash shells<sup>**4**</sup> to *unset* `PS1` automatically. As section [6.3.2 Is this Shell Interactive?](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) of the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) says:

> [S]tartup scripts may examine the variable `PS1`; it is unset in non-interactive shells, and set in interactive shells.

To see how this works, see the example there. Or check out the the real-world uses in Ubuntu. By default, `/etc/profile` in Ubuntu includes:

```bash
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi
```

`/etc/bash.bashrc`, which should do nothing at all when the shell is noninteractive, has:

```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

#### Subtleties of different methods of checking for interactivity:

To achieve the same goal, `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, which is copied into users' home directories when their accounts are created (so your `~/.bashrc` is probably similar), has:

```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

That's the other common way to check if a shell is interactive: see if the text obtained by [expanding](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) the [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) `-` (by writing `$-`) contains the letter `i`. Usually this has exactly the same effect. Suppose, however, that you have not modified the code shown above that appears by default in Bash's startup scripts in Ubuntu, and that:

1. you export `PS1` as an environment variable, *and*
2. it is set, but to the *empty* value, *and*
3. you start an interactive Bash shell...

Then `/etc/profile` (if it is a login shell) or `/etc/bash.bashrc` won't run the commands they usually run for interactive shells. `~/.bashrc` still will.

If you want to check if a shell is interactive by using `PS1` and get the right answer even when `PS1` is set but empty, you can use `[[ -v PS1 ]]` or `[ -v PS1 ]`/`test -v PS1` instead. Note, however, that the `[[` keyword, and the `-v` test of the `[` and `test` shell builtins, are particular to Bash. Not all other Bourne-style shells accept them. So you should *not* use them in scripts like `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` that might run in other shells (or by a display manager when you log in graphically), unless you have something else in the script that checks what shell is running and only executes Bash-specific commands when that shell is Bash (for example, by checking `$BASH_VERSION`).

---

### Notes

<sup>**1**</sup> [This article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) explains subshells in detail. [3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) of the Bash reference manual explains the `(` `)` syntax.

<sup>**2**</sup> Note that there are [circumstances](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358850/what-are-all-the-ways-to-create-a-subshell-in-bash) under which commands run in subshells even with the `(` `)` syntax is not used. For example, when you have [commands separated by `|` in a pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), Bash runs each of them in a subshell (unless the `lastpipe` [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) is set).

<sup>**3**</sup> Except for [subshells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell). Arguably that is not even an exception, since subshells don't "start up" in the usual sense that we mean when we talk about that. (They don't really have significant initialization behavior.) Note that when you run `bash`--with or without arguments--inside a Bash shell, that creates a subprocess that is a shell, but it is *not* a subshell.

<sup>**4**</sup> Note that not all shells--not even all [Bourne-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell)--behave this way. But Bash does, and it is very common for Bash code, including code in startup scripts, to rely on it.