# How can I find out the startup files read and environment variables created when Ubuntu was started with graphical interface

Tags: bash, startup, configuration, environment-variables

In Ubuntu 16.04 with LXDE or Gnome,

- how can I find out the environment variables created when Ubuntu was started with graphical interface?
- when Ubuntu was started with graphical interface, which startup files are read and executed,  `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bashrc`?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming LightDM, the `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` file is part of the answer. There you can see that for instance `~/.profile` is sourced when LightDM starts a user session.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite complex.

[Pam](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man7/pam.7.html) also can add environment variables, as well as other things (`login` program, `getty`, whatever...).

What I used to do is to add lines of the style (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds))

```
export CALLED_IN_ETC_PROFILE=$(date date +%s.%N)
```

in all suspicious files, and then look at the result for example using https://askubuntu.com/a/356973/16395.

To find which program/file could be responsible of the setting of a variable, you can try to look at the process tree of a shell into a terminal emulator:

```
[romano:/etc/X11/Xsession.d] % pstree -a -s -l -p -u $$
systemd,1 splash
  └─gdm3,1926
      └─gdm-session-wor,3752
          └─gdm-x-session,3807,romano --run-script gnome-session --session=gnome
              └─upstart,3824 --user
                  └─gnome-terminal-,5027
                      └─zsh,11224
                          └─pstree,11831 -a -s -l -p -u 11224
```

...I *think* that to start the graphic session, `gdm-x-session` is started from a user shell (note the UID change in the chain) in non-interactive mode, so that `.profile` is read (but not `.bashrc`, which is read by the shell in terminal emulator).

The tree is somewhat different if called from the `gnome-shell`:

```
bash-4.3$ pstree -a -s -l -p -u $$
systemd,1 splash
  └─gdm3,1926
      └─gdm-session-wor,3752
          └─gdm-x-session,3807,romano --run-script gnome-session --session=gnome
              └─upstart,3824 --user
                  └─gnome-session-b,4162 --session=gnome
                      └─gnome-shell,4278
                          └─xterm,11882 -e bash --noprofile --norc
                              └─bash,11884 --noprofile --norc
                                  └─pstree,11885 -a -s -l -p -u 11884
```

but this is expected.

BTW, a lot of environment variables could also be set before the UID change to the user; there are a lot of scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` and around that the `X` server, `gdm` (or whichever display manager you use), that can set environment variables.

Comment: Thanks. I found that in a shell started by Alt+F2 and `lxterminal -e bash --noprofile --norc`, `PATH` contains a path I set in `~/.profile`. So does it mean Ubuntu reads and executes `~/.profile` when it is started with graphical interface? What startup files does your Ubuntu read and execute when it is started with graphical interface?