# The nature of echo $COLUMNS

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

When we execute the command `echo $COLUMNS`, where is `COLUMNS` located? I thought it was just an environment variable, but it is not displayed in `env`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COLUMNS` is a shell variable, not an environment variable. Therefore, you will not find it when you use `env`. If you are not sure what the differences between a shell variable and an environment variable are, take a look at [Environment variable vs Shell variable, what's the difference?](https://askubuntu.com/q/26318/15003).

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/275972/15003, you can find `COLUMNS` if you run

```
( set -o posix; set ) | grep COLUMNS
```

which, on my machine, gives

```
COLUMNS=206
```

Comment: With the fish shell, `set | grep COLUMNS` provide me the answer.